# Elmah logs hundreds of files

Tags: c#, elmah

Learned error logging from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/logging-error-details-with-elmah-cs) and using [this](https://elmah.github.io/) . But Elmah logs one file to each error, and we end up with hundreds of hundreds of XML files. How can I set it up to log an entire day to one XML file?

This is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

....

  <elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="yes" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="C:\elmahlog" />
  </elmah>

</configuration>
```

Comment: XML can be well formed or not well formed.  A well formed xml as one root element.  When not well formed you have an array of elements at the root.   Log files usually are not well formed because you would need to insert data before the last closing tag.  So I would recommend just appending the logs to end of file so you only get one log file which is not well formed.

Comment: Thank you, but the decision to append log or not is embedded to elmah. I was hoping there was something to configure in web.config to change its behaviour.

Comment: You probably need to set up a scheduled task or similar, deleting files older than x days. You can use the file date or parse the date included in the filename.

Comment: I already have that @thomasardal, but it's not enough :(